# Laravel database select dropdown with placeholder

Tags: php, select, laravel, placeholder

Hi I'm populating a select dropdown with clients that exist in my database, however I want a placeholder first e.g. `Please select a Client`. Does anyone know the syntax?

This is what I have so far:

```
@if(count($client_options)>0)

    {{ Form::select('client', $client_options , Input::old('client'), array('placeholder' => 'Please select a client', 'id' => 'select_client', 'class' => 'chosen-select select', 'tabindex' => '2', )) }}

@endif
```

The placeholder attribute but that doesn't work, does anyone know how? Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you not just append another item to the clients array before you use it?

Comment: @mike how would i do that..? example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@if(count($client_options)>0)

    $client_options[] = "Please select a Client";

    {{ Form::select('client', $client_options , Input::old('client'), array('placeholder' => 'Please select a client', 'id' => 'select_client', 'class' => 'chosen-select select', 'tabindex' => '2', )) }}

@endif
```

Comment: that didn't work I'm doing this if statement in my view, it outputs this `$client_options[] = "Please select a Client";` in plain text

Comment: Do you have anything in the $clients_options array? If you don't then it won't ever enter the if statement.

Comment: Can you dd($client_options) just to check? Also, if you remove what I suggested, does it show you a list as you'd expect (obviously without the 'default' text).

Comment: array(3) { [2]=> string(16) "Client1" [3]=> string(8) "Client2" [1]=> string(17) "Client3" }

Comment: So you need to get just the clients' name...? At the moment, it looks like they are a collection (which is like an array but it has other features/properties). Can you paste more code here http://laravel.io/bin

Comment: yes correct i am assign a client to a project, so all i need is the client name for selection and i use the id to save to the db

Comment: `$client_options = DB::table('clients')->orderBy('client_name', 'asc')->lists('client_name','id');` this is my query @mike

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59023/discussion-between-mike-and-g-9020).

Comment: have accepted answer on basis of good advice on setting up a repository and implementing that way. have started this and is a really good clean way to go. so thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Assume that you are creating a dropdown list in Laravel form builder. Then the code should be like this -

In controller -

```
$categories = Category::select('id', 'name')->lists('name', 'id')->prepend('Select a category', '')->toArray();
```

and in view -

```
{!! Form::select('cat_id', $categories, old('cat_id')) !!}
```

Tested with Laravel 5.x.

Or if you have an array like -

```
$array = ['1' => 'lorem ipsum', '4' => 'Another text'];
```

And after passing this array to view -

```
{!! Form::select('cat_id', $array, old('cat_id')) !!}
```

There will be no placeholder. If you pass below array -

```
$array = ['' => 'Select category', '1' => 'lorem ipsum category', '4' => 'Another category'];
```

or there is a collection which you want to pass in view to build select/dropdown list then

```
$array = $collection->prepend('Select a category', '')->toArray();
```

You need to pass an array in order to build the dropdown list.

> Note: `array_unshift` or `array_merge` will not work as expected!

Comment: Nice, did not know about the  `prepend` functionallity. +1

Answer (score 0):

Just prepare the select in your controller with the placeholder and pass it to the view like:

```
$client_options = ['Select a Client'] +  Client::lists('field_name', 'id');
```

Then in your view you may check if the `$client_options` has more than one item in it, for example:

```
@if(count($client_options) > 1)
    {{
        Form::select(
            'client',
             $client_options ,
             Input::old('client'),
             array(
                 'id' => 'select_client',
                 'class' => 'chosen-select select',
                 'tabindex' => '2'
             )
        )
    }}
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone lands here trying to figure out how to set an item as selected, here's a hint.

The **third** array element in Form:select sets what item is selected:

```
Form::select('number', [0, 1, 2], 1)
```

The third element can also be an array for setting multiple items as selected:

```
Form::select('number', [0, 1, 2], [1,2])
```

The **placeholder** is always array element 0. To set the placeholder as selected, make sure the Form:select array element 3 is zero or has zero in the array:

```
Form::select('number', [1, 2, 3], [0,1], ['class' => 'field', 'placeholder' => $var])
```